# Why does my meteoric only randomly show the ionic html boilerplate?

Tags: javascript, node.js, meteor, ionic-framework, meteoric

I am working on a meteor app for smartphones with ionic.

Unfortunately the boilerplate code of ionic which shows the background-color and the back button are shown on some of my sites, and on some not.

It appears random to me but maybe it is not.

How can I get the ionic theme to be shown for all of my templates?

A description of project details and what I tried so far is going to follow now......

**Here is a list of my packages:**

```
aldeed:collection2       2.3.1* Automatic validation of insert and update operations on the client and server.
anti:i18n                0.4.3  Internalization: simplest package
fourseven:scss           2.0.1_5* Style with attitude. Sass and SCSS support for Meteor.js (with autoprefixer and sourcem...
iron:router              1.0.9  Routing specifically designed for Meteor
mdg:reload-on-resume     1.0.4  On Cordova, only allow the app to reload when the app is resumed.
meteor-platform          1.2.2  Include a standard set of Meteor packages in your app
meteoric:autoform-ionic  0.1.5  Ionic theme for Autoform
meteoric:ionic           0.1.17  Ionic components for Meteor. No Angular!
meteoric:ionic-sass      0.1.9  Ionic's CSS Framework in SASS and bundled for Meteor.
meteoric:ionicons-sass   0.1.6  Ionic's Ionicons library in SASS and bundled for Meteor.
spacebars                1.0.6  Handlebars-like template language for Meteor
```

**Here is a description of a test I made and screenshots concerning the issue:**
For my template named: "about" the ionic theme is shown.
I did copy the template code into a file named about2.html and named the template about2. I added a route named about2. The result was that for about.html ionic works as expected but for about2.html not.

I checked the included css files, were the same for both pages.

The by javascript generated html code was different.

**Here is the code of my about template:**

```
    <template name="about">

    {{#contentFor "headerButtonLeft"}}
        <div class="buttons">
            {{>myIonBackButton path="main" }}
        </div>
    {{/contentFor}}


    {{#contentFor "headerTitle"}}
        <h1 class="title">{{i18n 'about.title'}}</h1>
    {{/contentFor}}

    {{#ionView}}
        {{#ionContent}}
            <p>
                {{i18n 'about.content'}}

                Hello world

                {{i18n 'backButton'}}
            </p>
        {{/ionContent}}
    {{/ionView}}
</template>
```

**Here is how I set up the routes:**

```
Router.map(function(){

  /*Main menu*/

  this.route('about');
  this.route('about2');


});
```

**Here are screenshots which show the issue I do have:**
the about route
[image]

the about2 route
[image]

I also tryed:

- to debug the application with *meteor debug* without having a clue
  how to do that right concerning my issue
- to reset my application with *meteor reset*
- to run my application as an android app

**Why does my layout not show up propperly for every view?**

Comment: You have one template called about and another called about2, and they have exactly the same code in them, but are showing different things?

Comment: Thats right.
about2 is in about2.html in the folder client/templates/about2 

about is in about.html in client/templates/about

There is no javascript code which modifies the templates, that I have written.

I even tried it with different browsers, to ensure it is no caching issue.

Comment: http://altergear.net/media/tmp/p131_uploaded.zip 
This 77kb reset meteor project  reproduces the error.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by rewriting the routes.js file.

The default layout was not set.

```
Router.configure({
  layoutTemplate: 'appLayout'
});
```

Still confusing for me is, why ionic showed the layout sometimes, if it was not set.

I first followed [this](http://www.manuel-schoebel.com/blog/iron-router-tutorial) tutorial, but it is from 2013 and so seems to be too old. Also, as zerovapor in #meteor told me, it is not clear if Router.map is still supported. So I will use Iron-Router as specified in [this later tutorial](http://meteortips.com/second-meteor-tutorial/iron-router-part-1/).